# Подскажите плз простой способ авторизации через соц сети с главной страницы django проекта

Tags: python, django, windows-7, facebook

Создан проект по видео урокам `shadrus`.

Нужно дополнительно сделать авторизацию через соц сети.
Также проблема: как правильно переназвать `127.0.0.1:8000` чтобы Fb принял этот адрес как реальный.
Работаю под windows7

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то Вам необходимо выставить наружу ваше приложение. Т.е. получить реальный IP адрес, доступный извне (у провайдера, у администратора) и обеспечить маршрутизацию с него на ваш хост (но не на 127.0.0.1, а на другой IP адрес вашего хоста). Дополнительно можно привязать доменное имя (не обязательно). Указанный Вами IP адрес 127.0.0.1 является технологическим loopback адресом, и не доступен извне ни FB, ни другим внешним сервисам.

Что касается авторизации приложения django с помощью соцсетей, я полагаю, можно поискать какие-либо компоненты django для этого, вполне вероятно, что такие уже кем-то написаны. Например, почитайте здесь: http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/oauth.html

Comment: Я вижу что вы поняли мой вопрос про IP,но не вижу способа реализации,о котором спрашивала.какая функция в командной строке может есть для этой процедуры?

Answer (score 0):

> как правильно переназвать 127.0.0.1:8000 чтобы Fb принял этот адрес как реальный

Никак. Это технически невозможно. Вам требуется статичный внешний IP. Можно либо оплатить эту услугу у своего интернет-провайдера, либо арендовать VPS и развернуть проект там.